# Anker hubs are suddenly short on power - are USB ports failing?

Tags: charging, power, accessories

For the past 4 years I have been using Anker hubs to connect my Macbooks to a BenQ monitor and a Logitech wireless mouse.  Everything has worked fine until late last week when the back left port on my 16" 2019 MacBook Pro (big MBP) started complaining that my Anker A8383 is drawing too much power despite being plugged in to a big Apple power brick (80W?), and says it won't use it.  There is an error in the upper right of my screen that says something, but I can't get it to trigger right now.

The big MBP won't charge with the power cable plugged directly into the back left port, either.  If I move the Anker hub to the front left port, it will charge and the monitor will be detected and used, but the mouse won't.  I have a second Anker hub (A8346) that has the same problem (again, starting late last week).  If I plug the mouse into a different port on the right of the big MBP (using a USB-A to USB-C adapter), it works just fine.  Restarting the big MBP doesn't fix the problem, even temporarily.

I also have a 13" 2020 MacBook Pro and all of this stuff works as usual.  Because it doesn't appear to be any of the devices, it must be the USB ports and the left USB3/Thunderbolt port bank has started to fail.  Has anyone seen this before?  Maybe something hinky is going on with updates (which I must do on the big MBP but not the small one)?